# What's the best way to record a skype conversation?

Tags: video-quality, streaming, video-recording

I need to record a skype conversation and upload it to youtube (it's a live conference and the other party asked for it). 
Can I record a skype conversation? What would be the best way in terms of quality?

I have different systems available (Windows xp | 7 | 8, Debian 7 or Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), I'll use the one that suits the job better.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12395/how-can-i-record-my-skype-calls

Comment: Thanks! Which do you think would be the best way among these?

Comment: I have added two suggestions as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with these apps (as they are both free)

http://ifree-recorder.com/index.htm

http://voipcallrecording.com/

Answer (score 1):

A free solution could be with `ffmpeg` or other tools recording directly the monitor where you are running the call, maybe if you have multiple monitors you could consider running skype full screen in another monitor without showing your cam.

This solution could work if you have not the need of grabbing only the internal skype remote video input, and if you have enough space and a bit of time to cropping the final result at the end.

It could allow you by using a lossless codec to save a 100% identical quality of original call or even stream out the video somewhere else with different bitrates in a well known ffmpeg streaming workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Bandicam is a fantastic tool, it costs roughly $30; and does screen capture perfectly. Capture whole; part/region, fully configurable as to frame rate, codecs, and very easy to use interface. The playback quality is fantastic. I run it on all of my systems and it auto launches at startup.

I run 1 FPS all the time, with auto pause on no change in frame, so I can go back to any moment on my computer if I lose a file, etc. I have a record of every thing I do just as backup.

Great product.